# Button for submit form in Formik not working

Tags: next.js, axios, formik, next-auth, yup

I am trying to create a form using Next.js and using Formik to send a POST request with a valid and active session which is generated in a previous step.

Even though I used the same logic for a similar form to register users, I am not receiving any response when I click the Register Game button, neither I receive the logs in the console.

This is my code:

```
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import FormTitle from '../others/FormTitle';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { axiosInstance } from '@/lib/axios-instance';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const GameRegisterForm: React.FC = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    const initialValues = {
        title: '',
        publisher: '',
        releaseYear: '',
        description: '',
        genre: [''],
        platforms: [''],
        image: '',
    };

    const validationSchema = Yup.object({
        title: Yup.string().required('Title is required').max(100, 'Title is too long'),
        publisher: Yup.string().required('Publisher is required').max(50, 'Publisher is too long'),
        releaseYear: Yup.number().required('Release year is required').positive().integer().max(new Date().getFullYear(), `Release year cannot be in the future`),
        description: Yup.string().required('Description is required').max(1000, 'Description is too long'),
        genre: Yup.array().of(Yup.string().required('Genre is required')).min(1, 'At least one genre is required'),
        platforms: Yup.array().of(Yup.string().required('Platform is required')).min(1, 'At least one platform is required'),
        image: Yup.string().required('Image link is required').url('Please enter a valid image URL'),
    });

    const handleSubmit = async (gameData: any) => {

        if (!session || !session.user.token) {

            console.error('No active session or valid token');
            return;
        }

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', gameData.title);
        formData.append('publisher', gameData.publisher);
        formData.append('releaseYear', gameData.releaseYear);
        formData.append('description', gameData.description);
        formData.append('genre', JSON.stringify(gameData.genre));
        formData.append('platforms', JSON.stringify(gameData.platforms));
        formData.append('image', gameData.image);

        console.log("Game data before sending to the server: ", gameData);

        try {
            const response: AxiosResponse = await axiosInstance.post('/games', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${session.user.token}`
                },
            });

            if (response.status === 201) {
                router.push('/success');
            } else {
                console.error('Error registering game', response.data);
                alert('Error registering game');
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error('Error registering game:', error.response.data);
            alert('Error registering game');
        }
    };


    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                {({ values }) => (
                    <Form className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 w-full">
                        <FormTitle title="Register Game" />
                        <ErrorMessage name="errorMessage" component="div" className="mb-4 text-red-500" />
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="title">
                                Title
                            </label>
                            <Field
                                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="title"
                                type="text"
                                name="title"
                                placeholder="Title"
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name="title" component="div" className="text-red-500" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="title">
                                Publisher
                            </label>
                            <Field
                                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="publisher"
                                type="text"
                                name="publisher"
                                placeholder="Publisher"
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name="publisher" component="div" className="text-red-500" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="description">
                                Description
                            </label>
                            <Field
                                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="description"
                                component="textarea"
                                name="description"
                                placeholder="Description"
                                rows={4}
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name="description" component="div" className="text-red-500" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="genre">
                                Genre
                            </label>
                            <FieldArray name="genre">
                                {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                                    <div>
                                        {values.genre.length > 0 &&
                                            values.genre.map((genre, index) => (
                                                <div key={index} className="flex mb-2">
                                                    <Field
                                                        className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                                        name={`genre.${index}`}
                                                        placeholder="Genre"
                                                    />
                                                    <button
                                                        type="button"
                                                        className="ml-2 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                                                        onClick={() => remove(index)}
                                                    >
                                                        Remove
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            ))}
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                                            onClick={() => push('')}
                                        >
                                            Add Genre
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </FieldArray>
                            <ErrorMessage name="genre" component="div" className="text-red-500" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="platforms">
                                Platforms
                            </label>
                            <FieldArray name="platforms">
                                {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                                    <div>
                                        {values.platforms.length > 0 &&
                                            values.platforms.map((platform, index) => (
                                                <div key={index} className="flex mb-2">
                                                    <Field
                                                        className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                                        name={`platforms.${index}`}
                                                        placeholder="Platform"
                                                    />
                                                    <button
                                                        type="button"
                                                        className="ml-2 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                                                        onClick={() => remove(index)}
                                                    >
                                                        Remove
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            ))}
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                                            onClick={() => push('')}
                                        >
                                            Add Platform
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </FieldArray>
                            <ErrorMessage name="platforms" component="div" className="text-red-500" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="image">
                                Image
                            </label>
                            <Field
                                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="image"
                                type="text"
                                name="image"
                                placeholder="Insert image URL"
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name="image" component="div" className="text-red-500" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-between text-center">
                            <button
                                className="primary-color hover:bg-orange-700 text-gray-100 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                type="submit"
                            >
                                Register Game
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
};

export default GameRegisterForm;
```

I've tried to look for similar errors but I can't find a solution yet.

I can post more of the code if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.